# fnDraw clearing but not reloading DataTable Datasrc MVC JSON Api

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-ajax

How can I get it to refresh on the click of the button or else on a timer every minute or so? Thank you.

This is how it looks when I click on "Refresh". It clears the data but doesnt reload it.

[image]

Here's the View code.

```
<h2>Fixtures</h2>

    <button id="Refresh" type="button">Refresh</button>

    <table id="fixtures" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fixture</th>
                <th>Market</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

    @section scripts
{
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#fixtures").DataTable({
                    ajax: {
                        url: "/api/fixtures",
                        dataSrc: ""
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            data: "eventName",
                        },
                         {
                            data: "marketName"
                        }
                    ]
                });
                var oFixtureTable = $('#fixtures').dataTable();

                $("#Refresh").click(function (e) {
                    oFixtureTable.fnClearTable(0),
                    oFixtureTable.fnDraw();
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

EDIT: Simply changing the DataTable to the variable assignment as suggested below causes the DataTable to not render at all (regardless of any additional refresh coding).

```html
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //$("#fixtures").DataTable({
                var FixtureTable = $("fixtures").DataTable({
                    ajax: {
                        url: "/api/fixtures",
                        dataSrc: ""
                    },
```

[image]

Comment: Generally you should post code as markdown formatted text (indent by 4 spaces) instead of as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a refresh button it may be easier to use the [buttons](https://datatables.net/download/) option from the download builder. Or if you just want to download and include it as a single file, use e.g https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js

Then you could use:

```
var Fixturetable = $("#fixtures").DataTable({
        ajax: { 
           // ajax setup 
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        columns: [
            {
                // your columns
            }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Refresh Table',
                action: function () {
                   Fixturetable.ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        ]
     });
```

Also see example [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/reload.html) to get idea (its for 'Retain selection on reload' but shows how to use button) - documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/button/) & [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/).

Comment: Love that James, works beautifully! Thank you again (Y)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the Hungarian notation (`fnFoo`, `oTable`, `aBar`) was outdated in the move from Datatables 1.9 to 1.10. Since you have some options not using that notation, I assume you're using 1.10+.

The reason your code doesn't work how you want is that you first clear the table (destroying all rows) then **redraw** the table. Note that you aren't **reloading** the data, just drawing the table again. While there may be a 1.9 version of reload, I'm going to give you the 1.10+ solution, which is what you probably should be using.

To reload the table, simply call `TableName.ajax.reload()`. See documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()).

Another detail to note is that you're initializing your datatable, then assigning it to a variable, but you can and should do that in one step. Instead of having:

```
//Make sure you use the capital D, lowercase creates a table, uppercase returns an API object
$("fixtures").DataTable({
    //.......
});
var oFixtureTable = $("fixtures").dataTable();
```

You should have:

```
//Might as well get rid of the 'o' (though you don't have to)
var FixtureTable = $("fixtures").DataTable({
    //.......
});
//Don't need the other assignment now.
```

Then you'll change the inside of your refresh method to:

```
FixtureTable.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: Thank you, Chris.

See Edit above  Assigning DataTable to variable causing DataTable to not render at all. And yes Version 1.10.11

Comment: Struggling to integrate columns with variable method.